# What's the proper way to access an EJB3 Bean from within a Tapestry Page class?

Tags: java, tapestry

I want to use an EJB3 from within my Tapestry Page class, I can do JNDI lookup for it, but it will me much convenient to use EJB injection or Tapestry IoC. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! You can either contribute your EJBs via Tapestry's IOC container, so you would do the JNDI lookup in your build methods instead of all over your code (see the [manual](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5.1/tapestry-ioc/service.html) for information).

Or you could wire up your EJBs as Spring beans (see [the Spring EJB documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/ejb.html) for details), and use [Tapestry-Spring](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5.1/tapestry-spring/) to allow injecting them into your components via `@Inject`.